# Pre-joining students, classes, and grades in DynamoDB

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I am trying to model 3 entities using single table design. They are classes, grades and students in a college. Students have grades for each class they take. A student may take several classes, and a class may be taken by many students. Here is my [ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBPl1.png).

My access patterns:

1. Get grades and class information for student ID
2. Get grade and class information for student ID and class ID
3. Get all class
4. Get class by class ID

I am modelling the data like this: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL7TH.png) [Inverted index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEHIH.png).

Access patterns:

1. I am not sure how to change my model to accomplish this. Is it possible?
2. I can query for pk = class-ID, sk = class-ID OR student-ID
3. I can make a new field on all class called "type" and set it to "class". I can make a GSI on type field. Then I query for GSI PK = class.
4. I can query pk = class-ID.

How can I do #1? Is there a better way to do #2 and #3?

Comment: Do you have a code sample you can show?

Comment: @Beefster I do not. I have not yet written any code. This is purely a data modeling and database design question.

Answer (score 0):

I could come up with below suggestions for 1 and 3:

1. Duplicate class data for all students. This is noSQL, if data will be "static" you may want to do this. Then you only need to query by `pk = student-ID`
2. Looks good
3. If you keep class data as a different item (you don't apply 1st point), you could change SK to be a fixed value like "class". This way, you won't need an extra field nor an extra GSI and you could query, using inverse index by `sk = class`

Comment: Too bad, class data can change so I can not duplicate it for all students. Is it not possible to query what I want for #1? Your suggestion is good for #3.